# How to merge from SpatialLite to PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, merge, postgis, spatialite

How can I merge a SpatiaLite database to a PostGIS database?

I tried to use pgloader with the following command:

```
pgloader db.sqlite3 postgresql:///mydb
```

But it is not working. (I guess it is not supported). Please see the error output:

```
KABOOM!
FATAL error: Could not prepare an sqlite statement.
Code ERROR: no such module: VirtualSpatialIndex.
Database: /tmp/db.sqlite3
SQL: PRAGMA table_info(`SpatialIndex`)

An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Could not prepare an sqlite statement.
Code ERROR: no such module: VirtualSpatialIndex.
Database: /tmp/db.sqlite3
SQL: PRAGMA table_info(`SpatialIndex`)




FATAL: Failed to start the monitor thread.

error opening #P"/tmp/pgloader/pgloader.log": Permission denied
```

I use in SpatialLite only the simple POINT field. Nothing else from SpatialLite. (With Lat/Lng values)

**EDIT1:
@Corion**

If I try to do your way I get no error doing this:

```
pgloader --before load_spatialite.sql db.sqlite3
```

**But** loading it to PostGIS with this command:

```
pgloader --before load_spatialite.sql db.sqlite3 postgresql:///mydb
```

gives me the following error message:

```
2018-10-10T11:29:16.056000Z ERROR Database error 42883: function load_extension(unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY: SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')
KABOOM!
FATAL error: Database error 42883: function load_extension(unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY: SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Database error 42883: function load_extension(unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY: SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')




What I am doing here?

Database error 42883: function load_extension(unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY: SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')
```

What is here the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=mod_spatialite) is an extension built into SQLite. You will need an SQLite binary / library that is built with SpatiaLite linked statically or load the SpatiaLite dynamic extension (see link) while importing.

From staring at the [`pgloader` manpage](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgloader.html), it seems that you can prepend SQL commands to load the SpatiaLite extension into SQLite like this:

```
pgloader --before load_spatialite.sql  /tmp/db.sqlite3
```

and `load_spatialite.sql` contains

```
SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
```

You may or may not need to set up additional environment variables such that dynamic libraries are found for your process.

Comment: Thank you for the fast respond. I get a new error now (I edited my post because the error message is long)

Comment: `ERROR Database error 42883: function load_extension(unknown) does not exist` - maybe your SQLite library was compiled without `SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION` , which makes that function available. You can only find that by finding out how your SQLite library was compiled.

Comment: I use Debian 9 and installed everything from the repositories. How can I see if it was compiled with this option? I guess it is not compiled with this option, so what can I do?

Comment: I don't really know - either take it up with the `pgloader` developer(s) or with the package maintainer(s) of the Debian SQLite package, or with the package maintainer(s) of the Debian `pgloader` package, or maybe compile your own `libsqlite` and use that for building `pgloader` from source. I don't think any of these options are really great options, so maybe exporting from SQLite to CSV and then importing into Pg is a better option?!

Comment: I tried it with the docker image from pgloader website but there is the same problem. I will ask the developers of pgloader. Maybe there are going to fix this problem ...

Comment: According to pgloader documentation (see man pgloader) the before commands are performed on target database... so the function load_extension would not be recognized because you are performing it on postgresql target database, not on sqlite source database.